# the integer type of value gets an error on DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I tried this code, here:

```
@Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configure,
            ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaConsumerFactory,
            KafkaTemplate<Object, Object> template) {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        configure.configure(factory, kafkaConsumerFactory);
        factory.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(template),3));
        return factory;
    }
```

The int on this part

```
factory.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(template),3));
```

which is the number 3 isn't allowed as it requires BackOff rather than int type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That constructor was deprecated in 2.3.x and removed in 2.5.x.

See the documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#seek-to-current

> Previously, the configuration was "maxFailures" (which included the first delivery attempt). When using a FixedBackOff, its maxAttempts property represents the number of delivery retries (one less than the old maxFailures property). Also, `maxFailures=-1` meant retry indefinitely with the old configuration, with a `BackOff` you would set the maxAttempts to Long.MAX_VALUE for a `FixedBackOff` and leave the maxElapsedTime to its default in an `ExponentialBackOff`.

The equivalent now is

```java
factory.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(template), new FixedBackOff(0L, 2));
```

(no delay 3 delivery attempts).